# How do I insert a partial from a directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a custom directive like below. In it I'd like to insert html from a partial:

```
.directive('myDirective', function($parse){ 
return { 
  restrict: 'A', 
  scope: { foo: '=' }, 
  link: function(scope, element, attrs){ 
    //add children to element[0] using html from partials/content.html
    //...
  }
});
```

Google/Stack doesn't reveal much, is there a way to do this or am I not meant to use directives in this way?

Comment: does `templateUrl: 'somePartial.html',` instead of `link:` not do what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 possible things that you can do

1. You could either make `$templateRequest` to the html page, which internally make an ajax to fetch html & then put that html inside the `$templateCache`.

**Code**

```
$templateRequest('mypath.html').then(function(res){
   //inside you could have html content in res.data;
   var html = res.data;
})
```

2. You could put that `html` content inside `$templateCache` service inside run block & then use it whenever required using `$templateCache.get('templateName')`

**Code**

```
app.run(function($templateCache){
    $templateCache.put('mytemplate.html', '<div>My HTML</div>')
})

//inside directive do below thing
var html = $templateCache.get('mytemplate.html');
```

3. Place the html content inside script block which will have `type="text/ng-template"` which will again force this template to put inside the `$templateCache` service. and this template will make you available instantly.

**Markup**

```
<script type="text/ng-template">
    <div>My Content<div>
</script>

//inside directive you need to access it from $templateCache.
var html = $templateCache.get('mytemplate.html');
```

Comment: Why not just use `ng-include`? Also, there is a simpler-than-$http option of using `$templateRequest` that does the caching automatically.

Comment: @NewDev `ng-include` that would make a child scope which would be prototypically inherited from the directive..which doesn't make sense? I'm agreed on the `$templateRequest` stuff..will update my answer

Comment: You're talking about `ng-include`? That's true (and there isn't an inherent drawback with a child scope), but kind of orthogonal to the question. You, yourself, sidestepped it in your own answer by not showing what scope you would link against

Comment: Thanks @PankajParkar, found this too which helped me:   https://gist.github.com/nmacmunn/62976e5742d2527e242b